# what is problem in my code when i insert data in database name is db2 it is giving me ann error Column 'Name' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data in database name `db2` table name is `table1` from the registration form but it is giving me below error as "*Column `Name` cannot be null*" which i am not understanding, please help me

My controller name is `Abc.php` and code is

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Abc extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){

      $this->load->database();
      $this->load->model('Done');
      $this->load->view('codingregi');

                        $data = array(  
                        'Name'     => $this->input->post('name'),  
                        'Email'  => $this->input->post('email'),  
                        'Password' => $this->input->post('password'), 
                        'Gender'   => $this->input->post('gender')  

                        );  
         $this->Done->savingdata($data);
         redirect('Abc/index'); 


      }
}
?>
```

Model name is `Done.php` and is

```
 <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
    class Done extends CI_Model
     {
     public function savingdata($data)  
        {  
            //this array is used to get fetch data from the view page.  
         //$xyz = "insert into table1 values ('$name','$email','$password','$gender')";
      //$this->db->query($xyz);  
     {
          $this->db->insert('table1',$data);
          $emp_id = $this->db->insert();
        } 
        return emp_id;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and Registration form name is `codingregi.php`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>registraion form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" method="Abc.php">
    Name:<input type = "text" name="name"><br></br>
    email: <input type = "email" name="email"><br></br>
    Password: <input type ="password" name="password"><br></br>
    Gender: <input type ="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
            <input type ="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br></br>

    <input type ="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
```

Below is the complete error description

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'Name' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `table1` (`Name`, `Email`, `Password`, `Gender`) VALUES
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
>
> Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: is the Column `Name` type set to not Null? if so, it can then only accept a value

Comment: You have passed `NULL` values from the registration form, include the required attribute `<input type="text" id="textbox" required/>` or may as well do some validations using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

it could be like that your Name column is not null by default. You can change it by executing the following command.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE `name` varchar(255) NULL;
```

if the column is not null by default you have to provide a value while inserting a record else it will complain like so.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Controller:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
    class Abc extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){



          $this->load->view('codingregi');




          }

    public function save(){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Done');
        $data = array(  
                  'Name'     => $this->input->post('name'),  
                  'Email'  => $this->input->post('email'),  
                  'Password' => $this->input->post('password'), 
                  'Gender'   => $this->input->post('gender')  

                  );  
        $this->Done->savingdata($data);
        redirect('Abc/index'); 

        }

    }
    ?>
```

In Your View

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= base_url() ?>/abc/save">
```

Comment: Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Filename: views/codingregi.php

Line Number: 7

it is giving me this error

Comment: Poorwa Kesharwani base_url() is a function in ci which Returns your site's base URL, as specified in your config file.Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html. You have to load it in your project like $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); in application/config/autoload.php